# Is there a way to perform dynamic replacing in a regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

Is there a way to do a regex replace in C# 4.0 with a function of the text contained in the match?

In php there is something like this:

```
reg_replace('hello world yay','(?=')\s(?=')', randomfunction('$0'));
```

and it gives independent results for each match and replaces it where each match is found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) methods that have a `MatchEvaluator` overload.  The `MatchEvaluator` is a method you can specify to handle each individual match and return what should be used as the replacement text for that match.

For example, this...

> The cat jumped over the dog.
>   0:THE 1:CAT jumped over 2:THE 3:DOG.

...is the output from the following:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace MatchEvaluatorTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "The cat jumped over the dog.";
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            Console.WriteLine(Transform(text));
        }

        static string Transform(string text)
        {
            int matchNumber = 0;

            return Regex.Replace(
                text,
                @"\b\w{3}\b",
                m => Replacement(m.Captures[0].Value, matchNumber++)
            );
        }

        static string Replacement(string s, int i)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}:{1}", i, s.ToUpper());
        }
    }
}
```