# How to replace string with incrementing int in .NET?

Tags: .net, string, replace, increment

If I have a string:

```
mystring = "<p></p><p></p><p></p>"
```

so basically 3 empty paragraphs

if I want the end result to be:

```
<p id='1'></p><p id='2'></p><p id='3'></p>
```

how can I do that using replace or similar function? (in c#)

Comment: A “regex” would work here. Use a form that accepts a match replacement function (MatchEvaluator), such that the correct number can be selected for each match dynamically — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace (YMMV on regular expressions and HTML/XML in general; presumably this is a small well-defined case.)

Comment: not familiar with using Regex, code please?

Comment: In this case a match pattern of `@"<p>"` is sufficient. Then return `$"<p id='{i}'>"` from the MatchEvaluator after assigning the correct value to `i`. (Using a counter `i` variable in the outer scope is recommended.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use regex replace with the help of `MatchEvaluator`. Credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5585602/12354911) SO answer.

```
public static void Main()
    {
        string text = "<p></p><p></p><p></p>";
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.WriteLine(Transform(text));
    }

    static string Transform(string text)
    {
        int matchNumber = 0;
        return Regex.Replace(text, @"<p>", m => Replacement(m.Captures[0].Value, matchNumber++));
    }

    static string Replacement(string s, int i)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} id='{1}'>", s.Replace(">", ""), i + 1);
    }
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fqVZwv)

Comment: if I wanted to add a prefix to the id returned, can I add another argument to Replacement function? , then output like id='{2}{1}'....because I try it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @E.D. did you check the fiddle. It was running. And yes you can pass another `Replacement` function

Comment: ya I did try it in fiddle and it didn't work.  I meant modify the existing Replacement function to accept another argument (the prefix). Your code works, but not when I add the extra argument and try and use it like mentioned

Comment: @E.D. You mean something like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E51JQO)

Comment: ya but mine doesn't work for some reason, will have to take a close look why. You are doing the same thing I am basically

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit XML, you should use proper XML methods

```cs
var yourString = "<p></p><p></p><p></p>";

var x = XElement.Parse("<Root>" + yourString + "</Root>");
var i = 0;
foreach (var element in x.Elements("p"))
    element.Add(new XAttribute("id", i++));

Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(x.Nodes()));
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IyAgwq)